# MPMoviePlayerController Crashing on iOS 7 when stopped

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for playing video in my app.
It is working perfectly fine till iOS 6 and lower. But it is crashing on iOS 7 when i stop the MPMoviePlayer Object.

```
[player stop];
```

The error msg is:

```
-[__NSCFType _postNotificationName:object:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175927b0
2013-09-24 14:46:20.539 myAppName[446:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType _postNotificationName:object:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175927b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30133f53 0x3a9406af 0x301378e7 0x301361d3 0x30085598 0x31370bd7 0xb2e19 0x328d9f3f 0x328d9edf 0x328d9eb9 0x328c5b3f 0x328d992f 0x328d9601 0x328d468d 0x328a9a25 0x328a8221 0x300ff18b 0x300fe65b 0x300fce4f 0x30067ce7 0x30067acb 0x34d62283 0x32909a41 0xafeeb 0xafe78)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm seeing this error too.. Currently trying to figure out if there's some sort of conflict with 'MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification'.

UPDATE: I had my MPMovieplayer instance set to NULL in my MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification method. Moving that to my movieplayer instantiation method fixed the crash:

videoTrack = NULL

videoTrack = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

Comment: Did you subclass MPMoviePlayer to create your own notification posting method then? I'm seeing this when I call the stop method via a 3rd party library, just wondering if they might have done the same thing. As far as I can tell it never reaches my method that is listening for the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not calling `[player stop]` twice. iOS 7 calls to playbackFinish callback leave your player in an invalid state. It was happening exactaly the same with my application, until I discovered I was overreleasing the player because of PlaybackFinish method.